# React MUI Collapse Horizontally but expand left instead of right

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React and the MUI library. I would like to make a collapsible panel but expand the panel to the left instead of the right (like the examples https://codesandbox.io/s/hzppw6?file=/Demo.tsx). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You should reverse the direction of the flex container.

```
 <Box
    sx={{
      "& > :not(style)": {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        height: 120,
        width: 250,
        flexDirection: "row-reverse" // this is added
      }
    }}
  >
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  </Box>
```

Comment: FYI This doesn't do anything except re-order the examples on the page.  I could be wrong, but I don't think that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Correct. I have a "right panel" that I want to collapse and then when expanded, expand left (e.g. shrinking the rest of the page). There is a discussion here (https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/10051) about adding horizontal collapse and in the sort of example near the bottom the third panel does what I'm looking for...unfortunately there is no code for that in that post.